# Understanding different UUID outputs

Tags: post, uuid, multipartform-data

I need to make a POST with a multipart form. I've never ventured into this area so forgive any noobness.

When I POST to the site's route, its normal operation prints out this:

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryopMDmKAp2SnWwAzI
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="error_url"

I'm currently using a script created by a coworker that utilizes [Node UUID][1] and this is what it puts out:

> ------FormBoundary-7de21530-68fd-11e3-a14f-37e8c06fffa5
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="error_url"

Naturally, when I POST it doesnt work. I'm assuming its because the IDs at the end are different. Is the site's format a different ID convention? Or at the end of the day, should both be compatible with each other?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

This is what I have in the content type boundary:

> contentType: 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----FormBoundary-7de21530-68fd-11e3-a14f-37e8c06fffa5'

Comment: You need to put that UUID into the `Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=XXX` line.

Comment: The form boundary can be any string, it just has to match what's in the `Content-type` header.

Comment: @Barmar gotcha. I edited with that I send in the content type header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header should be:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----FormBoundary-7de21530-68fd-11e3-a14f-37e8c06fffa5
```

Capitalization isn't significant, but you need a hyphen between `content` and `type`. And there shouldn't be any quotes around the rest of the header field.